# "EOF in backquote substitution" when trying to run a binary file

Tags: binary, google-cloud

I get the following error when trying to run a binary file with the command: `tmp/123.bin`

`tmp/123.bin: 1: tmp/123.bin: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution`

I have no idea what could be causing the error as this is a script related error message, and I'm trying to run a binary file.

The file is created with the following (nodejs) code.

```js
await runCommand(`nasm -f elf32 ./tmp/${id}.asm -o ./tmp/${id}.o`);
await runCommand(`ld -m elf_i386 ./tmp/${id}.o -o ./tmp/${id}.bin`);
await runCommand(`chmod +x tmp/${id}.bin`);
```

I have no issue executing the file on my dev machine (wsl, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)
However when trying to do the same thing on Google Cloud Run the command fails.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Edit: here is some info I managed to find out.

`ls -l ./tmp/123.bin` → `-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 956 Oct 30 18:24 ./tmp/123.bin`

`file ./tmp/123.bin` → `./tmp/123.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped`

`uname -a` → `Linux localhost 4.4.0 #1 SMP Sun Jan 10 15:06:54 PST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: That binary is not recognized as a valid executable by the system, so the shell tries to run it as a script (as required by the standard, etc). I never used it, but I suspect that "Google Cloud Run" supports only x86-64 (amd64) binaries and does not include compatibility with 32bit x86 (as most Linux distros do).

Comment: As it turns out you are 100% correct Cloud Run only supports 64bit executables. Any suggestions on how I could manage to run a 32bit executable tho? I'm thinking of like a compatibility layer or something that I could install, as I cannot compile my program to 64bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can only run 64-bit executables on Cloud Run

[Executables in the container image must be compiled for Linux 64-bit](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#:%7E:text=Executables%20in%20the%20container%20image%20must%20be%20compiled%20for%20Linux%2064-bit)

However you can use [qemu](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/user/main.html)!

After you add `apt install -y qemu-user` to your Dockerfile you can run a 32-bit binary with the command `qemu-i386 ./file`